# Enable button if validation errors are valid JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

This is my javascript

```
<script>

    $('#submitform').submit(function() {
        if ($(this).find('.input-validation-error').length == 0) {
            $(this).find('button').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $(this).find('button').prop('disabled', false);
            }
    });

</script>
```

the problem is when I submit and I have validation errors like required field, button submit are disabled so I need to reload page to enable button again... Why else loop don't works correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Once the button is disabled it cannot be pressed again.

Comment: How can I change this to enable button if validation error are true?

Comment: You need to enable it again whenever user changes value of any form input

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking handler on `submit` hence it will test it once `submit` event is fired. If `button` is disabled, no event will be invoked over it.

Use `input` event over all the `:input` elements to validate!

```js
var handler = function() {
  if ($(this).find('.input-validation-error').length == 0) {
    $(this).find('button').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $(this).find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  }
};
$('#submitform').submit(handler);

$('#submitform').on('input', ':input', handler.bind($('#submitform')));//`.call` to pass `this` in the handler!
```

Comment: I try your code, but if I move any value of my form, button is disabled automatically, why it happens?

Comment: On which event, you want to validate it ? Try `$('#submitform').on('change',` if that helps!

Comment: That I want to do is prevent multiple submit, so when I press submit button it disabled as I want but if there are any error on submit my I get it and it´s ok, but the problem is my submit button is disabled too, and I cant submit form correctly if I dont reload page

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) quickly ?